# Python JSON API parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing, data-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out how to parse price data and get the average price for each submodel. I can make a request and get specific data but how do you go about getting the sum for specific models.

```json
"Toy X":{

    "toy a":{

        "submodel": "dx"

        "price": 2,
    }
    "toy b":{

        "submodel": "ed"

        "price": 5,

}
```

Basically group the toys by submodel then return the average price for each submodel.

current code:

```
response_API = request.get("toysforyou")
def _get_sub_group(query_url):
        # print(response_API.status_code)
        data = response_API.text
        # convert and decode the data into proper JSON format below
        parse_json = json.loads(data)
        # get all the toys of the same subclass
        group_subs = parse_json["toy x"]["submodel"]["price"]
        res = defaultdict(list)
        for i in group_subs:
            res[i["submodel"]].append(float(i["price"]))
        res = {k: mean(v) for k, v in res.items()}
```

Comment: I can't tell by comparing the snippet of `json` to your code whether the `json` is not right or whether you are getting a runtime error. Can you check your post again to see whether everything is correct?

Comment: Can you show a real excerpt of the data you are working with, and the intended output? The JSON you show is not valid so I don't think it really has that structure.

Comment: You have more than one same keys in your json. It can not be parsed into a dict in python.

Comment: @quamrana ive edited my sample

Comment: @Stuart the intended output would be: (ed: 5, xd: 2)

Comment: Besides that your sample is still not valid `json`, are you getting any errors when you run your code?

Comment: Do you only need to loop within "Toy X"? or are there other top level toy names/types?

Comment: Is JSON object returned from server contains just one `"Toy X"` key or there are also `"Toy Y"`, `"Toy Z"`, etc.? Do you want calculate average between submodels in same object or globally?

Comment: @Stuart there "brand: hasbro" at top level that expands down to "Toy X" and its submodels and price.

Comment: @OlvinRoght "brand" is the top level and then it goes to "Toy X" and its submodel and price. sorry for the missing info

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an actual [mre]. Make sure the input is valid and that the code actually works by itself; if you are sure the request itself works, hardcode the payload directly into the code instead of having a mock request. Please accurately state what output you expect, and what you get instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only need to look within "Toy X", you can iterate over the values in the dict, like this.

```
from statistics import mean
from collections import defaultdict

def get_mean_price_by_submodel(data):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    for v in data.values():
        r[v["submodel"]].append(v["price"])
    return {k: mean(v) for k, v in r}

data = request.get("toysforyou").json()
print(prices_by_submodel(data["Toy X"]))
```

It's best to request and parse the JSON separately (this can be done in one line `data = request.get("toysforyou").json()`) and send only the required dictionary to the function.

Alternatively, convert your JSON to a pandas dataframe, especially if you are doing substantial data manipulation and analysis.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["Toy X"], orient="index")
print(df.groupby("submodel").mean("price"))
```

Comment: Interesting, by parse seperatly you mean house it like so? 'def _get_sub_group(query_url):
    data = response_API.text
    parse_json = json.loads(data)
    group_subs = parse_json["toy x"]["submodel"]["price"] ' then the function you have?

Comment: @nataku I mean, having a separate function that takes a Python dictionary as a parameter and outputs another dictionary is clean, short, easy to understand what it does, and easy to test. So it's better not to include the lines that fetch the JSON and parse it inside that function. However fetching the JSON can be done in one line `data = request.get("toysforyou").json()` so doesn't really need its own function.

Comment: thanks alot, im still having trouble getting the logic down. An easier example -> 'import requests, json
from collections import defaultdict
from statistics import mean

# request and parse the data

response_API = requests.get("https://data.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json").json()

def get_mean_price_by_submodel(response_API):
    r = defaultdict(list)
    for v in response_API.values():
        r[v["Andaman and Nicobar Islands"]].append(v["deceased"])
    return {k: mean(v) for k, v in r}

print(get_mean_price_by_submodel(response_API["State Unassigned"]))'

Comment: @nataku sorry I can't read your code in a comment. The code in my answer is my suggestion for how to structure this. Consider asking another question if you have a follow up